# My minecraft block height is only 16 is it a glitch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently I've been working on an adventure map in a normal unmodded vanilla world, but my max block height is only 16. Please help I've been looking for an answer for over a month.

Comment: Did you use a flat world generator, or the normal one? Are you running this on a separate server? When you are standing on the ground, what Y coordinate does the debug screen (open with F3) show?

Comment: Voting to close since this user hasn't been seen since they asked this, and the question doesn't have enough details to answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running a server, make sure that in `server.properties`, `max-block-height` = 256.  If you are in single player, do a force update in the Minecraft launcher.